# How to create virtual rows in Oracle SQL without causing a cartesian join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a dynamic form for a 360 questionnaire in Oracle APEX. The form is for an employee to enter employees who will rate him at various levels. The number of ratees for each level can be between a minimum and a maximum, and therefore I would like to generate required and optional select lists in a dynamic report using apex_item.

My report query works nice when no employees have been selected previously, but fails when employees have previously been selected, or when I save and it redisplays the selected employees.

I started with this query:

```
select sub.display_name,
       sub.display_sequence,
       sub.number_list,
       sub.required_ratee,
       apex_item.popupkey_from_query
       (
          p_idx          => 2 * rownum - 1,      -- in    number                Which G_FXX global is populated.
          p_value        => sub.rater_person_id, -- in    varchar2 default null Current value.
          p_lov_query    => 'select papf.full_name d, 
                                    papf.person_id r
                             from   apps.per_all_people_f papf
                             where  (papf.current_employee_flag = ''Y'' or papf.current_npw_flag = ''Y'')
                             and    trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
                             order  by 1', -- in    varchar2
          p_width        => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_max_length   => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_form_index   => '0',           -- in    varchar2 default '0'
          p_escape_html  => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_max_elements => 300,           -- in    number   default null
          p_attributes   => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_ok_to_query  => 'YES',         -- in    varchar2 default 'YES' Immediately search.
          p_item_id      => 'SURVEY_RATEE' || to_char(2 * rownum - 1), -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_item_label   => null           -- in    varchar2 default null
       )  ratee_id
from   (       
          select rg.display_name, 
                 rg.display_sequence, 
                 nums.number_list,               
                 case when nums.number_list <= rg.min_persons then
                    'Yes'
                 else
                    'Optional'             
                 end required_ratee,
                 rg.rater_person_id
          from   (
                    select xsnv.person_id,
                           xsrm.rater_person_id,
                           xsrg.display_name,
                           xsrg.display_sequence,
                           xsrg.min_persons,
                           xsrg.max_persons,
                           sum(xsrg.max_persons) over () sum_max                     
                    from   xxpay_survey_nom_veri_type             xsnvt
                    inner  join xxpay_survey_nom_verifiers        xsnv
                    on     xsnv.nom_verifier_type_id = xsnvt.nom_verifier_type_id
                    and    xsnv.project_id = 1
                    inner  join xxpay_survey_ratee_group          xsrg
                    on     xsrg.questionnaire_id = xsnvt.questionnaire_id
                    left   outer join xxpay_survey_ratee_members  xsrm       
                    on     xsrm.project_id = 1
                    and    xsrm.ratee_group_id = xsrg.ratee_group_id
                    and    xsrm.person_id = xsnv.person_id
                    where  xsnvt.questionnaire_id = 1
                    and    xsnvt.nom_verifier_type = 'E'  -- Employee
                    order  by xsrg.display_sequence
                 )  rg,       
                 (
                    select rownum number_list
                    from   apps.per_all_people_f papf                 
                 )  nums
          where  rg.person_id = 6598
          and    nums.number_list <= rg.max_persons
          order  by rg.display_sequence, nums.number_list
       )  sub
order  by sub.display_sequence, sub.number_list
```

where I use the `nums` sub query and `and    nums.number_list <= rg.max_persons` to make virtual rows, which correctly gives me 18 rows when there is no previous selections in `xxpay_survey_ratee_members`. However it gives me 7 or 40 rows never mind what I try now. Here is one of my tries:

```
select sub.display_name,
       sub.display_sequence,
       sub.number_list,
       sub.required_ratee,
       sub.rater_person_id,
       2 * rownum - 1 rn, sub.position_number
       apex_item.popupkey_from_query
       (
          p_idx          => 2 * rownum - 1,      -- in    number                Which G_FXX global is populated.
          p_value        => sub.rater_person_id, -- in    varchar2 default null Current value.
          p_lov_query    => 'select papf.full_name d, 
                                    papf.person_id r
                             from   apps.per_all_people_f papf
                             where  (papf.current_employee_flag = ''Y'' or papf.current_npw_flag = ''Y'')
                             and    trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
                             order  by 1', -- in    varchar2
          p_width        => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_max_length   => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_form_index   => '0',           -- in    varchar2 default '0'
          p_escape_html  => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_max_elements => 300,           -- in    number   default null
          p_attributes   => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_ok_to_query  => 'YES',         -- in    varchar2 default 'YES' Immediately search.
          p_item_id      => 'SURVEY_RATEE' || to_char(2 * rownum - 1), -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_item_label   => null           -- in    varchar2 default null
       )  ratee_id
from   (       
          select rg.display_name, 
                 rg.display_sequence, 
                 nums.number_list,               
                 case when nums.number_list <= rg.min_persons then
                    'Yes'
                 else
                    'Optional'             
                 end required_ratee,
                 rg.rater_person_id,
                 rg.position_number
          from   (
                    select xsnv.person_id,
                           xsrm.rater_person_id,
                           xsrm.position_number,
                           xsrg.display_name,
                           xsrg.display_sequence,
                           xsrg.min_persons,
                           xsrg.max_persons,
                           sum(xsrg.max_persons) over () sum_max                     
                    from   xxpay_survey_nom_veri_type             xsnvt
                    inner  join xxpay_survey_nom_verifiers        xsnv
                    on     xsnv.nom_verifier_type_id = xsnvt.nom_verifier_type_id
                    and    xsnv.project_id = 1
                    inner  join xxpay_survey_ratee_group          xsrg
                    on     xsrg.questionnaire_id = xsnvt.questionnaire_id
                    left   outer join xxpay_survey_ratee_members  xsrm       
                    on     xsrm.project_id = 1
                    and    xsrm.ratee_group_id = xsrg.ratee_group_id
                    and    xsrm.person_id = xsnv.person_id
                    where  xsnvt.questionnaire_id = 1
                    and    xsnvt.nom_verifier_type = 'E'  -- Employee
                    order  by xsrg.display_sequence                    
                 )  rg,       
                 (
                    select rownum number_list
                    from   apps.per_all_people_f papf                 
                 )  nums
          where  rg.person_id = 6598
          and    nums.number_list <= rg.max_persons
          order  by rg.display_sequence, nums.number_list
       )  sub              
where  (
          (
             sub.required_ratee = 'Yes'             
             and sub.number_list = sub.position_number
          )
          or
          (
             sub.required_ratee != 'Yes'
             and sub.position_number = 1
          )
       )
order  by sub.display_sequence, sub.number_list
```

Does anyone know how to fix my query to once again display 18 rows or is there potentially a better way of creating the virtual rows that would not have my issue. The issue is basically that there is a cartesian join when previous selections exist.

My tables are as follows:

`apps.per_all_people_f` is any table with lots of rows

```
xxpay_survey_nom_veri_type
nom_verifier_type_id,nom_verifier_type,display_name,nom_verifier_type_name,questionnaire_id,display_sequence
1   E   Employee        360 Questionnaire 2015 Employee     1   10
2   M   Line Manager    360 Questionnaire 2015 Line Manager 1   20

xxpay_survey_nom_verifiers
verifier_id,project_id,nom_verifier_type_id,person_id,verifier_person_id
2   1   2   6598    8362
5   1   1   6598    6598

xxpay_survey_ratee_group
ratee_group_id,ratee_group_name,display_name,min_persons,max_persons,display_sequence,questionnaire_id,ratee_group_type
1   360 Questionnaire 2015 - Self           Self            1   1   10  1   S
2   360 Questionnaire 2015 - Line Manager   Line Manager    1   3   20  1   M
3   360 Questionnaire 2015 - Colleagues     Colleagues      3   8   30  1   C
4   360 Questionnaire 2015 - Direct Reports Direct Reports  2   6   40  1   D


xxpay_survey_ratee_members
member_id,project_id,ratee_group_id,person_id,rater_person_id,verifier_person_id,reason,overriding_person_id,position_number
5   1   2   6598    8362    6598            1
6   1   3   6598    6591    6598            1
4   1   1   6598    6598    6598            1
7   1   3   6598    6232    6598            2
8   1   3   6598    8193    6598            3
9   1   4   6598    7104    6598            1
10  1   4   6598    8361    6598            2
```

`xxpay_survey_nom_veri_type` is a list of nomination verifier types. Nomination verifiers will verify the ratees someone who must be rated will choose.
`xxpay_survey_nom_verifiers` are the actual employees who will be the verifiers.
`xxpay_survey_ratee_group` is a list of classifications for ratees, which specify whether they are the employee himself, the line manager of the employee, etc. Each group has a minimum and maximum number of ratees.
`xxpay_survey_ratee_members` are the actual employees who will be raters in each ratee group. This is what my dynamic form will allow you to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got to:

```
select sub.display_name,
       sub.display_sequence,
       sub.number_list,
       sub.required_ratee,
       apex_item.popupkey_from_query
       (
          p_idx          => 2 * rownum - 1,      -- in    number                Which G_FXX global is populated.
          p_value        => xsrm.rater_person_id, -- in    varchar2 default null Current value.
          p_lov_query    => 'select papf.full_name d, 
                                    papf.person_id r
                             from   apps.per_all_people_f papf
                             where  (papf.current_employee_flag = ''Y'' or papf.current_npw_flag = ''Y'')
                             and    trunc(sysdate) between papf.effective_start_date and papf.effective_end_date
                             order  by 1', -- in    varchar2
          p_width        => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_max_length   => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_form_index   => '0',           -- in    varchar2 default '0'
          p_escape_html  => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_max_elements => 300,           -- in    number   default null
          p_attributes   => null,          -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_ok_to_query  => 'YES',         -- in    varchar2 default 'YES' Immediately search.
          p_item_id      => 'SURVEY_RATEE' || to_char(2 * rownum - 1), -- in    varchar2 default null
          p_item_label   => null           -- in    varchar2 default null
       )  ratee_id
from   (
          select rg.display_name, 
                 rg.display_sequence, 
                 nums.number_list,               
                 case when nums.number_list <= rg.min_persons then
                    'Yes'
                 else
                    'Optional'             
                 end required_ratee,
                 rg.sum_max,
                 rg.ratee_group_id
          from   (             
                    select xsnv.person_id,
                           xsrg.display_name,
                           xsrg.display_sequence,
                           xsrg.ratee_group_id,
                           nvl(xsro.min_persons, xsrg.min_persons) min_persons,
                           nvl(xsro.max_persons, xsrg.max_persons) max_persons,
                           sum(nvl(xsro.max_persons, xsrg.max_persons)) over () sum_max
                    from   xxpay_survey_nom_veri_type  xsnvt,
                           xxpay_survey_nom_verifiers  xsnv,
                           xxpay_survey_ratee_group    xsrg,
                           xxpay_survey_ratee_override xsro
                    where  xsnvt.questionnaire_id = 1
                    and    xsnvt.nom_verifier_type = 'E'  -- Employee                           
                    and    xsnv.nom_verifier_type_id = xsnvt.nom_verifier_type_id
                    and    xsnv.project_id = 1                           
                    and    xsrg.questionnaire_id = xsnvt.questionnaire_id
                    and    xsro.project_id (+) = 1
                    and    xsro.ratee_group_id (+) = xsrg.ratee_group_id
                    and    xsro.person_id (+) = 6598                       
                 )  rg,
                 (
                    select rownum number_list
                    from   apps.per_all_people_f papf                 
                 )  nums                    
          where  rg.person_id = 6598
          and    nums.number_list <= rg.max_persons
          order  by rg.display_sequence, 
                 nums.number_list          
       )  sub
       left   outer join xxpay_survey_ratee_members xsrm
on     xsrm.project_id = 1
and    xsrm.ratee_group_id = sub.ratee_group_id
and    xsrm.person_id = 6598    
and    xsrm.position_number = sub.number_list      
order  by sub.display_sequence, 
       sub.number_list
```